# Error when I run: git push heroku master

Tags: python, git, heroku

I cannot find out what is giving me errors. I can't push code to heroku. I followed an online course step by step but something on my side is causing the rejection. I tried starting everything from scratch but no luck. I keep arriving at the same problem.

**Git:**

```
> git push heroku master
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.42 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.12
remote:      $ pip install -r requirements.txt
remote:        Collecting click==6.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading click-6.6.tar.gz (283kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask==0.11.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading Flask-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (80kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114kB)
remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==0.24 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==2.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (263kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==0.23 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting Werkzeug==0.11.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading Werkzeug-0.11.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306kB)
remote:        Installing collected packages: click, itsdangerous, Werkzeug, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Flask, gunicorn
remote:          Running setup.py install for click: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for click: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for itsdangerous: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for itsdangerous: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'done'
remote:        Successfully installed Flask-0.11.1 Jinja2-2.8 MarkupSafe-0.23 Werkzeug-0.11.10 click-6.6 gunicorn-19.6.0 itsdangerous-0.24
remote:
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-grep", line 81, in <module>
remote:     main()
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-grep", line 76, in main
remote:     grep(**kwargs)
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-grep", line 45, in grep
remote:     r = Requirements(reqfile)
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-grep", line 25, in __init__
remote:     self.load(reqfile)
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-grep", line 36, in load
remote:     for requirement in parse_requirements(reqfile, finder=finder, session=requests):
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip/req/req_file.py", line 89, in parse_requirements
remote:     for req in req_iter:
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip/req/req_file.py", line 137, in process_line
remote:     isolated=isolated, options=req_options, wheel_cache=wheel_cache
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip/req/req_install.py", line 168, in from_line
remote:     if (os.path.isdir(p) and
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 49, in isdir
remote:     st = os.stat(s)
remote: TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed: cannot parse Procfile.
remote:  !     Please try pushing again.
remote:  !     If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com/ and provide Request ID 9da9f85c-09e1-40e9-b8fe-a09eff718783.
remote:
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to warm-ocean-27938.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/warm-ocean-27938.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/warm-ocean-27938.git'
```

**.git/config:**

```
. . .
[remote "heroku"]
        url = https://git.heroku.com/warm-ocean-27938.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Here's the **Procfile** that's causing the error. I'm not sure why it's not working as I followed the tutorial step-by-step. This is what I have in there:

```
web: gunicorn routes:app
```

I edited **Procfile** to remove white space after colon:

```
web:gunicorn routes:app
```

I then ran:

```
heroku create
```

After, I pushed it to heroku and received this error which is a bit different:

```
>git push heroku master
. . .
remote:        Successfully installed Flask-0.11.1 Jinja2-2.8 MarkupSafe-0.23 Werkzeug-0.11.10 click-6.6 gunicorn-19.6.0 itsdangerous-0.24
remote:
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-grep", line 81, in <module>
remote:     main()
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-grep", line 76, in main
remote:     grep(**kwargs)
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-grep", line 45, in grep
remote:     r = Requirements(reqfile)
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-grep", line 25, in __init__
remote:     self.load(reqfile)
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-grep", line 36, in load
remote:     for requirement in parse_requirements(reqfile, finder=finder, session=requests):
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip/req/req_file.py", line 89, in parse_requirements
remote:     for req in req_iter:
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip/req/req_file.py", line 137, in process_line
remote:     isolated=isolated, options=req_options, wheel_cache=wheel_cache
remote:   File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip/req/req_install.py", line 168, in from_line
remote:     if (os.path.isdir(p) and
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 49, in isdir
remote:     st = os.stat(s)
remote: TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 37.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://warm-ocean-27938.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/warm-ocean-27938.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Inside my project folder:

```
C:\Users\combatmath\apps\ocrbox [master ↑ +1 ~1 -0 | +0 ~4 -0 !]> ls -R


    Directory: C:\Users\combatmath\apps\ocrbox


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         8/6/2016   3:15 PM                .idea
d-----         8/6/2016   3:04 AM                ocrbox
d-----         8/5/2016   8:20 PM                static
d-----         8/6/2016   3:14 PM                templates
-a----         8/6/2016   3:16 AM             24 .gitignore
-a----         8/6/2016   2:16 PM             24 Procfile
-a----         8/5/2016   8:21 PM              0 README.md
-a----         8/6/2016   3:32 AM            232 requirements.txt
-a----         8/6/2016   3:04 PM            275 routes.py


    Directory: C:\Users\combatmath\apps\ocrbox\.idea


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/5/2016   5:59 AM              7 .name
-a----         8/5/2016   5:56 AM            706 misc.xml
-a----         8/5/2016   9:31 PM            288 modules.xml
-a----         8/5/2016   9:31 PM            663 ocrbox.iml
-a----         8/6/2016   3:00 PM            180 vcs.xml
-a----         8/6/2016   3:15 PM          29636 workspace.xml


    Directory: C:\Users\combatmath\apps\ocrbox\ocrbox


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/6/2016   3:04 AM            395 .gitattributes
-a----         8/6/2016   3:04 AM            696 .gitignore


    Directory: C:\Users\combatmath\apps\ocrbox\static


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         8/6/2016   2:49 AM                css
d-----         8/5/2016   8:20 PM                img
d-----         8/5/2016   8:20 PM                js


    Directory: C:\Users\combatmath\apps\ocrbox\static\css


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/6/2016   2:49 AM             26 main.css


    Directory: C:\Users\combatmath\apps\ocrbox\templates


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/6/2016   3:14 PM            133 about.html
-a----         8/6/2016   3:13 PM            277 base.html
-a----         8/5/2016   9:48 PM              6 header.html
-a----         8/6/2016   3:14 PM            293 index.html
```

Comment: You can see an error here: `Push failed: cannot parse Procfile.` Can you share the Procfile?

Comment: Can you edit with your Procfile? Also make sure your Procfile isn't Procfile.something

Comment: Yeah. I went and did a triple take to see if there was any different from the course and my file but none. Procfile is posted.

Comment: Can you post a list of all of the files in your directory please.

Comment: Sure. My project folder is now posted.